# Http Get method to display map in android

Tags: android, http-get

I have a google map code in xxx.php file. How to display that map using android application using Http Get method in android.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)
Much better approach is just use android libraries for Google maps.